# How can I delete a key from my JSON if its empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, mongoose

I am trying to delete the key from js object if key doesn't have value inside of it.

I have tried using delete foundBrief.Contents.url but not worked. I am doing this for alexa flash briefing skill. It throws error if the redirection url is blank I have to remove that attribute url in that case if its empty.

ContentSchema:

```
var contentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id : { type: String, default: uuid.v1},
     date: Date,
     titleText: String,
     mainText: String,
     Url: String,
     author:{
      id: {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: "User"
      },
      username: String
     }
 },{
            versionKey: false
    });
```

To display json object on the url using routes:

```
router.get("/:id/abcd.json", function(req, res) {
  Brief.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate("contents")
    .exec(function(err, foundBrief) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(foundBrief.contents);
       //[{"uid":"00a3b980-4ccc-11e9-ab44-dd6a45baec41","date":"2019-03-22T02:30:00.000Z","title":"title test","main":"content text","Url":""}]
        foundBrief.contents.forEach(function(element) {
            if(element.Url === ""){
                delete element.Url;
            }    
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Have this

```
[
  {
    uid: "00a3b980-4ccc-11e9-ab44-dd6a45baec41",
    date: "2019-03-22T02:30:00.000Z",
    title: "title test",
    main: "content text",
    Url: ""
  }
];
```

want this

```
[
  {
    uid: "00a3b980-4ccc-11e9-ab44-dd6a45baec41",
    date: "2019-03-22T02:30:00.000Z",
    title: "title test",
    main: "content text"
  }
];
```

Comment: `foundBrief.contents.forEach(...)` should work. Can you create a minimal snippet to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let obj of foundBrief.contents){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
      if(obj[key] === ''){
        delete obj[key];
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22544800)